# Reported defect, received refund, do not want to return item

Tags: fraud, refund

I reported to Graco that the lock down latch system was broken on the base of my car seat. This is the information that was given to me by my child's father. Graco issued me a refund and sent me a shipping label to return the defective product. Upon actually inspecting the product myself, there is nothing broken, but the latch isn't safely keeping the seat in place. I'm worried that reporting that a piece was broken and possibly returning an unbroken item could land me in trouble because I made the claim. I didn't want to return the item. I merely asked that they discount my next seat for my child since I would soon be buying the next seat up, and this is how the representative handled my call.

Do I return the base or the whole seat? What about the discrepancy in what was reported vs the actual findings? And do I keep the refund and use it towards the next seat? If I keep the refund and do not return the base, legally, what is the repercussions I should expect. I don't want to do anything wrong, but I do want to keep my child safe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer service issue.

Comment: If "the latch isn't safely keeping the seat in place," they why don't you want to return the item?

Comment: Just return it. Defective, Broken is relative to an extent.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question as [on-topic](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because this is a consumer issue.

Comment: They want to inspect seats with problems--to see how to keep the problem for recurring in new designs.

Answer (score 6):

If they've already issued you a refund, you should return the car seat.

You (and the child's father) are not expected to be an expert on whether or not the car seat is broken.  You spoke to the customer service representative, answered his or her questions as best you know how, and they essentially are buying the seat back.  If they gave you a refund for the whole seat and base, then that is what you should return.  They might be able to reuse the parts from it to make a new/refurbished seat.

Take the refund, return the entire product, and buy yourself a new seat that will fit your car.  I recommend going to a specialty baby supply store instead of a big box discount store; that way, a sales person can help you install your seat and ensure that it fits your car correctly.